# Gitlab CI: Stage variable based on global variable is not resolved when using anchors

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have something like this in my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
.docker_build_cmd: &docker_build_cmd >-
  docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG -f $DOCKER_FILE .

variables:
  PROJECT_NAME: best-app-ever
  BUILD_VERSION: 4.2.0
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: $DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME:$BUILD_VERSION

build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    GRADLE_CMD: app:build
    DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME: $PROJECT_NAME-service
    DOCKER_FILE: docker/service.dockerfile
  script:
    - echo $DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME
    - echo $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG 
    - *docker_build_cmd
```

but runner says:

```
$ echo $DOCKER_PROJECT_NAME
best-app-ever
$ echo $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG
$PROJECT_NAME-service:4.2.0
$ docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG -f $DOCKER_FILE .
invalid argument "$PROJECT_NAME-service:4.2.0" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Does anyone understand why it happens?
How Gitlab processes the .yml?
And if there is a way to make it work as I intended, I am really want to know.

GitLab SaaS version is 14.3.0-ee.

**UPD**. After some googling it seems that "variable_inside_variable" feature flag [has to be enabled](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#nested-variable-expansion). Will do it tomorrow and see what changes.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab CI "variable inside variable" feature was disabled, so I asked admins to toggle it and everything became fine. Don't think that this could be helpful question for many, because GitLab already enabled the feature globally, but if you have a standalone solution and the same issue, then you know what to do.